# Constant sectional curvature from $K_{ij}=-1,~\forall~ i,j=1,...,n; i\ne j$

Tags: riemannian-geometry

Assume $(M,g)$ is a smooth Riemannian manifold, $p\in M$ and $\{e_i\}\subset T_pM$ is orthogonal basis (may not normal). If I have
$$
K_{ij}=-1,~~~\forall~ i,j=1,...,n; i\ne j
$$
where $K_{ij}$ is the sectional curvature of plane generated by $e_i,e_j$. Then whether I can get
$$
K(\sigma)=-1,~~~\forall \sigma\subset T_pM
$$
where $\sigma$ is 2-dim plane contain origin.

This problem is from the 3-section  of 8-chapter  of do Carmo's Riemannian Gemetry. I feel his way is a little troublesome. Therefore, I want to get the constant curvature from the $K_{ij}=-1$. But I don't know whether this idea is right and how to prove it.

PS: I can't understand the Laz's explain. Who can talk it detail ? Thanks very much.

In the section 3 of chapter 8 of do Carmo's Riemannian Geometry, do Carmo give an example of a space of constant curvature $-1$. Let
$$
H^n =\{(x_1,...,x_n)\in \mathbb R^n; x_n >0\},~~~
g_{ij} (x_1,...,x_n) = \frac{\delta_{ij}}{x_n^2}
$$
Let $f=\ln x_n$, then
$$
x_n^2 R_{ijij} = -\sum_l f_l^2 + f_i^2 +f_j^2+f_{ii}+f_{jj}
$$
where $f_i =\partial_i f$. Besides, if all four indices are distinct, we have
$$
R_{ijkl}=0
$$
And if any three indices are distinct, we have
$$
R_{ijk}^i = -f_kf_j -f_{kj}, ~~~
R_{ijk}^j = f_i f_k +f_{ki},~~~
R_{ijk}^k = 0
$$
Then we have

> [image]

> [image]

> [image]

But in my view, do Carmo only prove
$$
K_{ij} = -1 
$$
If I want to get $K(\sigma)=-1$  for all $\sigma \subset T_pM$, I must to show $R_{ijkl}=0$ which have not the form $R_{ijij}, R_{ijji}$. do Carmo's proof seemly be not complete, since he do  not show $R_{ijjj}=0, (i\ne j)$. In fact, I am not sure how to understand  "all four indices are distinct",  whether it  contains $R_{1333}$.

Since I feel it's too much trouble and I feel my original question maybe right, I ask whether
$$
K_{ij}=-1,~~~\forall~ i,j=1,...,n; i\ne j  \Rightarrow 
K(\sigma)=-1,~~~\forall \sigma\subset T_pM
$$
If so, we don't need to calculate all $R_{ijkl}$.

Comment: Any 2-plane can be transformed into any other by a rotation, which is a linear isometry on $T_p M$.

Comment: @Laz  Could you talk it detail ?  I can't get you.

Comment: I don't have a copy of Do Carmo. Could you say precisely what the problem states? It is not true that if, given a point $p \in M$ and an orthonormal frame $(e_1, \dots, e_n)$ of $T_pM$, $K_{ij} = -1$, for all $i \ne j$, then  $K(\sigma) = -1$ for all $2$-dimensional linear subspaces $\sigma$ of $T_pM$.

Comment: @Deane  Thanks your help. I add the brief process of do Carmo and my motivation.  What you talking means my idea is wrong. Could you detail talk the counterexamples ?   If it is complex to  type, just tell me the reference is enough. Thanks again.